# Changing background of <span> inside an element

Tags: html, css

I have two `<span>` inside a list of `<div>`. Each div has different amount of text, hence the height is different for each one.

### Below is the HTML:-

```
<li class="correct">
    <div class="conclusion-q-area">

        <span class="q-c-area">Diam egestas dictumst maecenas adipiscing egestas tempus nullam ullamcorper elementum vel suspendisse hac accumsan dapibus sociosqu consectetur viverra ante enim ad id sodales parturient..</span>
        <span class="q-res-area"><i class="fa fa-times red"></i></span>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="correct">
    <div class="conclusion-q-area">

        <span class="q-c-area">Diam egestas dictumst maecenas adipiscing egestas tempus nullam ullamcorper elementum..</span>
        <span class="q-res-area"><i class="fa fa-times red"></i></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

The problem is that I am having hard time changing the background color of `span`  with class `q-res-area`. It seems that it pre-picks the height from somewhere and then restrict it with all rows. Here is the image that shows it. Notice the last row:-

[image]

### The CSS is:-

```
.correct {
  position:relative;
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #0065bd;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.conclusion-q-area span {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.q-c-area {width: 90%;}
.q-res-area {width: 10%; background-color: #F9F9F9; font-size: 20px;}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle.  I took your code and took a look at the fiddle and there are other pieces missing.  https://jsfiddle.net/uh1abdrv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Tables to the rescue!

```css
.correct div {
  display:table-row;
}
.correct div span {
  display:table-cell;
}

.red {
  color:red
}

.correct {
  display:table;
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #0065bd;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.conclusion-q-area span {
  padding: 15px;
}

.q-c-area {width: 90%;}
.q-res-area {width: 10%; background-color: #F9F9F9; font-size: 20px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="correct">
    <div class="conclusion-q-area">

        <span class="q-c-area">Diam egestas dictumst maecenas adipiscing egestas tempus nullam ullamcorper elementum vel suspendisse hac accumsan dapibus sociosqu consectetur viverra ante enim ad id sodales parturient..</span>
        <span class="q-res-area"><i class="fa fa-times red">X</i></span>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="correct">
    <div class="conclusion-q-area">

        <span class="q-c-area">Diam egestas dictumst maecenas adipiscing egestas tempus nullam ullamcorper elementum..</span>
        <span class="q-res-area"><i class="fa fa-times red">X</i></span>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```